# Convert rows to columns considering multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I have current base table:

[image]

and I need to convert it to this:

[image]

I already have a dynamic SQL in place which is giving me below result for the LTD values:

[image]

But I am not able to create dynamically the columns for the Aggregationname based on the columns LTD and BOY and set the post fix to the column name.

Find my SQL below:

```
create table #tempIE
(
    AGGREGATIONNAME varchar(2),
    LTD decimal,
       BOY decimal,
       MONTH int
)

insert into #tempIE values ('XX', 50, 45, 00)
insert into #tempIE values ('XX', 150, 145, 01)
insert into #tempIE values ('XX', 300, 295, 02)

insert into #tempIE values ('YY', 25, 20, 00)
insert into #tempIE values ('YY', 50, 45, 01)
insert into #tempIE values ('YY', 75, 70, 02)

insert into #tempIE values ('ZZ', 500, 495, 00)
insert into #tempIE values ('ZZ', 600, 595, 01)
insert into #tempIE values ('ZZ', 700, 695, 02)

SELECT *
FROM #tempIE



DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.AGGREGATIONNAME) 
            FROM #tempIE c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT MONTH, ' + @cols + ' INTO ##tempIEnew from 
            (
                select AGGREGATIONNAME
                    , LTD
                                 --, BOY
                    , MONTH
                from #tempIE
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(LTD)
                for AGGREGATIONNAME in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '
                    ;

execute(@query)



SELECT *
FROM ##tempIEnew

drop table #tempIE
drop table ##tempIEnew
```

Comment: This is one reason why I prefer conditional aggregation; it much easier (and less restrictive) to do things like this than `PIVOT`.

Comment: How would this look like for my use case?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server do you have?

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments, I much more prefer using conditional aggregation rather than the `PIVOT` operator, it's so much easier to work with as it's not got restrictive syntax.

With conditional aggregation, you can easily achieve a static pivot with the following:

```sql
SELECT IE.[MONTH],
       MAX(CASE IE.AGGREGATIONNAME WHEN 'XX' THEN IE.LTD END) AS XX_LTD,
       MAX(CASE IE.AGGREGATIONNAME WHEN 'YY' THEN IE.LTD END) AS YY_LTD,
       /* ... */
       MAX(CASE IE.AGGREGATIONNAME WHEN 'ZZ' THEN IE.BOY END) AS ZZ_BPY
FROM #tempIE IE
GROUP BY IE.[MONTH];
```

For a dynamic pivot, then you could achieve this with the following.

```sql
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

DECLARE @Delim nvarchar(3) = N',' + @CRLF

SELECT @SQL = N'SELECT IE.[MONTH],' + @CRLF +
              STRING_AGG(N'       MAX(CASE IE.AGGREGATIONNAME WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(IE.AGGREGATIONNAME,'''') + N' THEN IE.LTD END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(CONCAT(IE.AGGREGATIONNAME,'_LTD')),@Delim) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY IE.AGGREGATIONNAME) + N',' + @CRLF +
              STRING_AGG(N'       MAX(CASE IE.AGGREGATIONNAME WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(IE.AGGREGATIONNAME,'''') + N' THEN IE.BOY END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(CONCAT(IE.AGGREGATIONNAME,'_BOY')),@Delim) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY IE.AGGREGATIONNAME) + @CRLF +
              N'FROM #tempIE IE' + @CRLF +
              N'GROUP BY IE.[MONTH];'
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT AGGREGATIONNAME
      FROM #tempIE) IE;

--PRINT @SQL;--Your best friend

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Note I assume you are using a fully supported version of SQL Server (as it's not noted you aren't) and so there's no need to `FOR XML PATH` and 2 passes of the table. I also switch to creating the query inline, as attempting to that with a variable `@Columns` is a real pain with conditional aggregation; I actually don't recommend that method either cause it's respective (like `PIVOT`).

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1f963feb125b0ff65600eb540d21aceb)